# Why isn't my AlarmManager calling the Pendingintent

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, notificationmanager

I'm trying to make my application use AlarmManager to send a notification after 5 seconds, but the pendingIntent doesn't seem to get called.
Heres my code

In onCreate in MainActivity:

```
Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;
    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime , PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Notification.class:

```
public class Notification extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setTicker("Ticker")
            .setContentText("Text");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

}

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wouter.lifetracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".Notification"
        >
        </receiver>

</application>
```

i have searched for hours but i can't find out why nothing is happening

Answer (score 1):

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

> Note: Beginning in API 19, the trigger time passed to this method is
>   **treated as inexact: the alarm will not be delivered before this time,
>   but may be deferred and delivered some time later**. The OS will use
>   this policy in order to "batch" alarms together across the entire
>   system, minimizing the number of times the device needs to "wake up"
>   and minimizing battery use. In general, alarms scheduled in the near
>   future will not be deferred as long as alarms scheduled far in the
>   future.

Answer (score 1):

only 5 seconds?

try this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                showNotification(); //your notification code called after 5 seconds
                }
            }, 5 * 1000); // 5 seconds...
```

OR TRY:

```
long alertTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000); // <-- try this
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime , PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Yes it's only 5 seconds so that i can easily check wether it works or not, in the end it's supposed to go off once a day.

I tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work.
I'm testing this app on my phone so maybe it is just a problem with my phone?